# Calling on Enum class for reference

Tags: java

I have this enum class listed below. 
Enum class is:

```
public enum Direction {

    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    EAST, 
    WEST,
    NOWHERE
}
```

and instructions are when I move a vehicle from my other class called vehicle, it returns a direction (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, or WEST) to move that will take the Car one step closer to the target destination. The call to `nextMove()` should modify the internal state of the Vehicle object to reflect its new location given the direction it returned. If the current location of the Car equals the target destination, then `nextMove` should return "NOWHERE". SO I tried to address this creating if statements, as in, if it goes north, then it will print NORTH and vice verse. Here are the specs and my attempt:

if a Car is at position (3, 10) and it decides to move north, then it will move to position (3, 11). In general, if a car moves "north" from position (x, y) it will end up in position (x, y+1), "south" from (x, y) puts it in position (x, y-1), "east" (x+1, y) and "west" (x-1, y). As in, if the object moves upwards, then it will say "NORTH."

Current Attempt:

```
        public void Direction(Direction togo)  
        {
            if((yDestination+1)>yDestination)
            {
                System.out.println("NORTH");
            }

            if((yDestination-1)<yDestination)
            {
                System.out.println("SOUTH");
            }
            if((xCar+1)>xCar)
            {
                System.out.println("EAST");
            }
            if((xCar-1)<xCar)
            {
                System.out.println("WEST");
            }
```

I have attempted to answer this object above by the if statements but im pretty sure something is wrong.

Comment: Well your conditions don't make sense...

Comment: At least not to me.. because it appears that all if blocks will execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
According to your code,all the conditions will execute. Try out this..

Class Vehicle
{
    private int currentX,CurrentY;

    public void printDirection(int modifiedX,int modifiedY)
     {
            if(modifiedY>CurrentY)
            {
                System.out.println(Direction.NORTH);
            }

            if(modifiedY<CurrentY)
            {
                System.out.println(Direction.SOUTH);
            }
            if( modifiedX>currentX)
            {
                System.out.println(Direction.EAST);
            }
            if(modifiedX<currentX)
            {
                System.out.println(Direction.WEST);
            }
            currentX=modifiedX;
            currentY=modifiedY;
         }

          public static void main()
           { 
             Vehicle myVehicle = new Vehicle();
             myVehicle.printDirection(0,1);
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.. xPosition and yPosition is the current (x,y) of the Car.

```
class Car
{
    int xPosition = 0;
    int yPosition = 0;

    public void nextMove(Direction direction)  
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case NORTH:
                yPosition += 1;
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                yPosition -= 1;
                break;
            case EAST:
                xPosition += 1;
                break;
            case WEST:
                xPosition -= 1;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply print the `togo` object itself, at the end of the switch, to remove rodundant code.